# Are there any simple, stupid, module based, cross-platform, c++ projects that I can check out of a repository?

Tags: c++, cross-platform, module

I'm looking for one just to get a general idea of how a standard C++ project should be properly setup.
(If that's possible... :-p)

Here are my requirements for this project:

- module-based (has libraries/modules that compile into a main program module)
- compiles cross-platform

I'd like to do this so that I can get a hold on the basics of how a good C++ project is setup, and so that I can test out Premake.

Comment: Questions like this, without  a single possible correct answer,  should be community wiki

Answer (score 1):

http://code.google.com/p/csvfix/ - cross platform, simple make file, code includes library and executable in a single zip.

Answer (score 1):

[FW4SPL](http://code.google.com/p/fw4spl/) is a component-oriented architecture with the notion of role-based programming. FW4SPL consists of a set of cross-platform C++ libraries. Not yet simple, but with a properly setup.